# Отправить данные из Realtime Database при помощи Firebase Functions на email

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, firebase-database

Как при помощи Firebase Functions отправить определенные данные на email? 
Допустим, есть авторизированный юзер и какие-то его данные (например дата рождения) мы положили в Realtime Database. Как, при помощи Firebase Functions, сделать отправку этого поля на email после HTTP запроса?